Calculate time in the future and get timestamp from it python
I want to create /giveaway command which calculates actual time + time that giveaway will last and get timestamp from this time in the future
i tried to do this but i get date 1970 year
hours = 2
  
obj = time.gmtime(hours * 60) 
  
print(obj) 


If you search for the time.gmtime() function, you will find the Python documentation which explains

time.gmtime([secs])
Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a struct_time in UTC...

This is clearly not what you want.

Use the datetime module to get the current datetime and add some amount of time to it:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

end_datetime = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=num_promotion_hours)
print(end_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) # format however you want

You can pass in days, hours, and/or seconds as arguments to timedelta

Using the datetime library, this can be done in the following way. Keep in mind that if your datetime object is localized to a specific timezone, datetime can have problems around daylight savings time transitions and you should consider a different library.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_dt = datetime.now()
future_dt = current_dt + timedelta(hours=2)
print(future_dt.timestamp())


Maybe try doing something like this
import time

# Get current timestamp
current_timestamp = time.time()

# Specify future time in seconds (relative to current time)
# or just convert your additional time in whatever format to seconds
future_seconds = 60  

# Calculate future timestamp
future_timestamp = current_timestamp + future_seconds

# Print the timestamp
print(future_timestamp)

